# Word Doesn't Refresh Numpages

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm writing a Wordfile with VB.NET
It has footer with "Page X of Y", where X is a PAGE-Field and Y a NUMPAGES-Field
The problem is, Y doesn't fresh always on the first page. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.
I already tried using

```
 worddoc.Range().Fields.Update()
        For Each section As Word.Section In worddoc.Sections
            section.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Update()
        Next
```

But it stays the same.

If I look at the created Document after saving and the total number of pages should be over 3, Y is always 3 in my Document.
As soon as I scroll manually, with the Worddoc displayed, to an other Page it refreshes correctly.

How to solve this?

Comment: I checked it again, the code above works, while the document is opened by the program, the fields are correctly updated and the pagenumbers are correct.
But when I open the document later, again on page 1 Y is 3